# U2 Toolkit for .NET - Entity Framework Sample "EntityFramework_CodeFirst" not working

Tags: .net, u2, universe, unidata, u2netdk

When we try to run "EntityFramework_CodeFirst" and "EntityFramework_CodeFirst2" samples, we get the following error:

**Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'U2.Data.Client.U2Connection'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to answer this question myself.
You need correct version of Entity Framework 4.1. If you are using older version (assembly file version 4.1.10331.0), you will see this issue.
You need to install Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1 (assembly file version 4.1.10715.0)
See this link : http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/08/problems-with-entity-framework-4-1-update-1/